# Checking whether element is in list or not

Tags: list, haskell

I have just started writing my first few programs in Haskell and I'm struggling a lot - so please excuse  errors galore. I found this practice problem online and it wants me to take in a list, an int, and return a bool. I should check if the int is to be found within the list or not and return true or false, respectively.
This is what I have:

```hs
import Data.List

elem':: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
   elem' x [x] 
      | x == [x:xs] = True
      | length [x] == 1 = False
      | otherwise = elem' tail [x]
```

The compiler returns

> Illegal type signature [...] Type signatures are only allowed in patterns with ScopedTypeVariables

which I cannot really make sense of yet. I've found some people saying that this error occurs when using tabs instead of spaces, yet I solely used spaces. I am grateful for any advice!

Comment: Unless you are working with a list containing a single element, I would not use `[x]`.

Comment: Why did you indent `elem' x [x]`?

Comment: Your notation is messy.  Let `x` be the element (needle). Let `ys` be the list (haystack).

Comment: In many cases, when you need to define a function on lists, you need the cases `f [] = ...` and `f (x:xs) = ...`. Try following that pattern `elem y [] = ...` and `elem y (x:xs) = ...`. Avoid `head,tail,length,[x],[x:xs]` since they often lead you to a wrong and/or inefficient solution.

Answer (score 3):

First you have a simple indentation problem. Your definition is parsed as

```
elem':: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool elem' x [x] 
      | x == [x:xs] = True
      | length [x] == 1 = False
      | otherwise = elem' tail [x]
```

I'm a bit surprised that this isn't reported as a *parse* error, but basically it is one.

What you need to do is, indent all function clauses to the *same* level as the signature (i.e. in this case, not indented at all).

```
elem':: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem' x [x] 
 | x == [x:xs] = True
 | length [x] == 1 = False
 | otherwise = elem' tail [x]
```

This is still very wrong though. First, you're matching twice on `x`. This is not possible in Haskell. OTOH there's no variable `xs` in scope. If it were, it would have to have type `[a]`, and then `[x:xs]` would have type `[[a]]`: a nested list. But then comparing it to `x`, which is not even a simple list, doesn't make any sense. `length [x]` is always 1, regardless of what `x` is. Similarly, `tail [x]` is always the empty list (but that's not even what's used here, you've actually wrote that the `tail` function should be passed as an argument to `elem'`).

Perhaps the confusion comes from the fact that `[` `]` can mean two different things: one the *type level*, it means you're talking about lists of elements of the enclosed type. I.e. `[a]` is the type of lists whose elements have type `a`.
By contrast, on the *value* level, `[x]` is specifically the list that contains only a single element, namely `x`.

You should make sure you understand how pattern matching works. Your clause would have been legal if you had two different variables in it. Then, matching `[y]` would mean this clause only accepts lists with exactly one element, and `y` will than be the value of the single element. In this case, the correct implementation would be

```
elem' x [y] = x==y
```

(Alternatively, you could have guards here yielding `True` and `False`, but that's just redundant work.)

Actually though there's no good reason to have a clause for *exactly one element*. All you need is a clause for *zero* elements

```
elem' x [] = ...
```

and a clause for *at least one* element:

```
elem' x (y:ys)
 | ...
 | ...
```